# checkbox checked on label click before on change event is fired

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-3

In my following code what I want is when I click on **`label`** only new `dialog` should open and there when I `select option` true then it should automatically check the `checkbox`.

Problem is when I click on `checkbox` `label` it checks it before `dialog` is open.

[codepin](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYNqgO)

jQuery code

```
this.get = function(t) {
$.fancybox.open([
    {
      src:
        '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="checkbox checkbox-success"><select onchange="\'' +
        $(t)
          .find("input#checkbox1")
          .attr("checked", true) +
        '\'"><option value="Unclassified">False</option><option value="">true</option></select></div></div>',
      type: "html",
      smallBtn: true
    }
  ]);
};
```

Here is my html coode

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success" onclick="get(this);">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="styled" value="" onclick="">
    <label for="checkbox1"><a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="#">Test</a></label>
  </div>
```

Comment: in codepen demo, first you have a `checkbox` so you need check it to see `select option` right? then want to true `option` then see next `checkbox` ? it's kinda not clear what you asking and what exactly problem is

Comment: what I want is when I click on `label` of `checkbox` and dialog is open when `select option` is changed to true then it should check the `checkbox`.

Comment: @pedram check my edited question. hope now it's clear.

Comment: I don't know understand right or not, but what i get ( That's obvious when you click on `label` it going to check `checkbox`, you should change your code instead of prevent it. input id is `checkbox1` and your label has `for="checkbox1"` so it's ordinary to when you click on label it going to check input checkbox.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/wxeh99eo/ is it what you want? if yes tell me to explain in answer.

Comment: I read the question 3 times and still no idea what are you trying to describe.

Comment: @Janis you have solved my problem in my previous question. Thanks guys.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987351/check-checkbox-on-first-fancybox-when-select-value-changes-on-second-one